# I am not able to change my root password on Mac

Tags: mac, password

Ok so I need adb for a problem in my android phone. And for that I need my root password. So I tried to change it since I was not aware of it being a thing in the first place. I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfX5I_mnnYc. But I am not able to change it successfully since it tells me that my password is wrong every time. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no root user on macOS. You can just use sudo and your admin account password for adb — no need to change any passwords. It’s also very non-typical to run apps as root, so you might need to check with the app maker if you’re considering trying that to verify you are installing the app properly in the first place or don’t have a different error to solve than permissions.

You could have a problem if your Mac account has no password, so set one in the users pane of system preferences.

You can install most command line tools without root, Android sdk tools, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677431/where-to-install-android-sdk-on-mac-os-x